# Recommended windproof matches?

Tags: gear, fire-starting

I was looking for some good windproof matches - not for any specific use, but just because I considered they may come in useful in some environments.

Has anyone any experience with any particular ones? A lot of the ones I've searched for (such as [these](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Life-Systems-2270-Lifesystems-Windproof/dp/B001SGWIUU/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top)) don't seem to have many good reviews.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use [these from REI](http://www.rei.com/product/617046/rei-stormproof-matches).  I can attest that they work in both wind and rain, though needless to say you do need dry fuel.  Nothing will start sodden wood ;)

Comment: You beat me to it! These are great matches.

Answer (score 1):

Doug Ritter has what appears to be a pretty good summary of matches on his site: [Equipped.org](http://www.equipped.org/devices28.htm#StrikeOne)

Also, here is a video review of [a "stormproof" match kit](http://www.rei.com/product/820267/uco-stormproof-match-kit) from REI from someone who knows what he's doing (not me):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I34E2KNvnm0